# Como posso transformar um template bootstrap(html,css,javasript ) num .Zul (Views do framework Zk)

Tags: java, framework

Estou programando em Zk, gostaria de pegar num template Bootstrap e transformar pra uma Views de ZK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Theming_and_Styling/ZK_Official_Themes/ZK_Bootstrap_Theme) você pode baixar o arquivo jar do [Github](https://github.com/zkoss-demo/zk-bootstrap/releases) ou colocar a dependência no pom.xml.
Caso baixe do Github, você deve colocar o arquivo `zk-bootstrap.jar` dentro da pasta `WEB-INF/lib` do seu projeto.

Depois você adiciona a seguinte configuração no `zk.xml`

```
<library-property>
   <name>org.zkoss.zul.Button.mold</name>
   <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
   <name>org.zkoss.zul.Menupopup.mold</name>
   <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
   <name>org.zkoss.zkmax.zul.Navbar.mold</name>
   <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
   <name>org.zkoss.zul.Paging.mold</name>
   <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
<library-property>
   <name>org.zkoss.zul.Panel.mold</name>
   <value>bs</value>
</library-property>
```

Dependência Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.zkoss.addons</groupId>
   <artifactId>zk-bootstrap</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[Getting Started](https://www.zkoss.org/zk-bootstrap/) do ZK com Bootstrap